# Odoo 500 server internal error after installation of odoo

Tags: postgresql, odoo, internal-server-error, odoo-9

Hı all. Thank you for this community. I want use odoo for my job. but I'm so tired, I'm on the verge of giving up from odoo.

I would be very grateful if you help.

After installation, I can get once localhost8069 . And creating database.
 ANd ı take create database error.

Database creation error: "invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff " while parsing /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/base_data.xml:55, near     <span>--<br/> Administrator</span>

After this error  ı take always 500 internal server error. I can not see login interface anymore.  I just see 500 internal server error.

6 days I'm working and I could not reach a solution. I used ubuntu and pardus ( some kind debian) . And the results did not change.

But when ı used w7 ı succeed. I was able to get odoo. But ı want use odoo in linux not windows.

I guess this error about database. But ı didnt find source about confıgure postgresql for odoo. Can you help me pls ?

This is my steps  for installions of odoo  after fresh ubuntu :

1-)

```
wget -O - nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | apt-key add -
echo "deb nightly.odoo.com/9.0/nightly/deb/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update && apt-get install odoo
```

2-) and go : http://localhost:8069

Log file : ı erased log file and restart odoo server and try few time localhost:8069 again :

And this is end of new fresh log file :

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1554, in setup_db

httprequest.session.db = db_monodb(httprequest)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1701, in db_monodb

dbs = db_list(True, httprequest)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 1675, in db_list

dbs = openerp.service.db.list_dbs(force)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/db.py", line 323, in list_dbs
with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/sql_db.py", line 630, in cursor

return Cursor(self.**pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/sql_db.py", line 164, in __init**

self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/sql_db.py", line 513, in _locked

return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/sql_db.py", line 581, in borrow

**connection_info)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 164, in connect

conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)

OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Comment: There are more then one process run, you must kill this process before start your server

Comment: show your server traceback logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution. The problem is very simple. This problem is caused by using debian, which is not English. The English debian worked without error.

As a result, we always use the operating system in English.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try with the first solution:

Make sure the permission is correct for postgres engine by giving the correct one as the following:

sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /var/run/postgresql   (default directory)

Plus, make sure the port 8069 is open.

Comment: I guess IM just not well configure postgresql

Answer (score 1):

- try this command: ps -A
- check for postgresql & odoo proccess and kill them all
- do it for few times
- if you are using VMware like me restart it
- hope that answer your question